# Regex for checking if JavaScript input is in a particular format?

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I need to check whether the input date time is in either one of the three formats below? I am new to Regex so any help is much appreciated?

Valid Input:

- 6/1/2018 - 2:35PM
- 6/1/2018
- 2:35PM

Invalid Input:

Test

Invalid

125657

Comment: Welcome to [SO] please read the [ask] with [mcve] before asking

Comment: Why is everyone so rude when it comes to helping people ? He asked for a simple regex, it could be a good exercise for him ! And we don't need any code sample or sandbox, regexes are easy to make. Anyway, see my answer below and tell me what you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You request, I deliver :

```
let regex = /((\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{1,4} - \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}[AP]M)|(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{1,4})|(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}[AP]M))/
```

Use [Scriptular](http://scriptular.com/) to test, build, and understand regexes.

Comment: By the way, I can explain the regex to you, but I think it's a good exercise that you try by yourself : this is a very simple regex, and discovering it by yourself might be very helpful.

Comment: The above Regex seems to validate 6/01/2017 but not 6/1/2017

Comment: I don't know if you changed it, but on my side, it works for both

Comment: Be mindful of the spaces ! no spaces are allowed here

Comment: Yup it works I forgot to add global while testing

Comment: Good ! Mark it as resolved if you have no more questions